# Import text file from drop-down in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro in Excel that imports a text file based on values in cells on a worksheet. One cell specifies the path of the directory, a second cell with a drop-down contains the file's name including extension.

I've tried to record a macro wherein I import a file from the directory in question, but I am having trouble changing it so that it uses the two cells with the path and file name instead of constant values.

The original recorded macro looks as follows:

```
Sub txt_import()
' txt_import Macro
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="testfile", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""D:\testpath\testfile.txt""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=10, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Colu" & _
    "mn4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=testfile;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [testfile]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "_testfile"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

The directory path is located on Sheet1 A1 and the drop-down list with the file names is in Sheet3 A2.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify the Source query string, try:

```
Sub txt_import()
' txt_import Macro
Dim path as String, filename as String, fullFileName as String
path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
filename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value
fullFileName = path & Application.PathSeparator & filename
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="testfile", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(" & fullFileName & "),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=10, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Colu" & _
    "mn4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"""
```

Comment: tried this, results in run-time error 424 ("object required" in line 4, i.e., path = ...

Comment: I have a typo in my answer, should be `ThisWorkbook` not `ThisWorkbooks`

Comment: I've corrected the typo, thanks. now I'm getting `run-time error 1004` ("application defined or object defined error") in line 27.

I've changed that line to
    `.ListObject.DisplayName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value`

Comment: if you've changed your code, please also edit your question so that it reflects the code you're currently using. otherwise it's quite literally impossible for me to do anything beyond mere guesswork. do note that ThisWorkbook and ActiveWorkbook are not (necessarily) the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the advice and your help, I will update the post & code ASAP, just have to finish some other stuff first!